# Call SQL server stored procedure with JPA 2.1 annotations

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-boot

I'm attempting to call a MS SQL server stored procedure. Im using spring-boot, JPA 2.1, hibernate.

The database has a table with isbn, title, author, description and the stored procedure i'm trying to call takes one in parameter(isbn) as a string and returns only the title.

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.procedure.ParameterStrategyException: 
Attempt to access positional parameter [2] but ProcedureCall using named parameters
```

Anyone got a solution for this or know what the error means? I have also tried other combinations of annotations.

Book.java

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "bookList", 
        resultClasses=Book.class,
        procedureName = "dbo.list_books", 
        parameters = {
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "isbn", type = String.class)
          })
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
     }    
}
```

BookRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Procedure
    Iterable<Book> list_books(String arg);  
}
```

BookService.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    protected BookRepository bookRepository;

    @RequestMapping
    public Iterable<Book> books(){
        return bookRepository.getBooks("1111111");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem with annotations, i worked around it with an EntityManager and a StoredProcedureQuery.

The Book.java is the same but without the @NamedStoredProcedureQuery. I removed the repository and rewrote the service like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BookService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books",
            params = {"isbn"},
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public  List<Book> getByIsbn(@RequestParam(value = "isbn") String isbn){
        StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("name.of.stored.procedure", Book.class);               
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("isbn", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        sp.setParameter("isbn", isbn);

        boolean result = sp.execute();
        if (result == true) {
            return sp.getResultList();
        } else {
            // Handle the false for no result set returned, e.g.
            throw new RuntimeException("No result set(s) returned from the stored procedure"); 
        }
}

}
```

It is now possible to call this endpoint with a stringquery like: http://localhost/api/books?isbn=1111111